# Scraping a website using Python and printing to a file conflict

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape some data from a website and then write the extracted data in a file. This is related to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229316/scraping-the-second-page-of-a-website-in-python-does-not-work).

In the answer there is this function:

```
def get_books(data):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

    for title in soup.select("div.zg_itemImmersion div.zg_title a"):
        print title.get_text(strip=True)
```

And the whole thing works great. But, as soon as I add a line to write the book title in a file, then I see that not all the book titles are displayed on screen. As if there is a conflict somewhere or there is a time sensitive function somewhere.

The code that will behave strangely will be alone this line:

```
def get_books(data):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
    f = open('myFile','a')
    for title in soup.select("div.zg_itemImmersion div.zg_title a"):
        print title.get_text(strip=True)
        f.write(title.get_text(strip=True))
    f.close()
```

Comment: Can you provide an example site?

Comment: Here is an example: http://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Books-Architecture/zgbs/books/173508/#1, please see the question that I refer to for full details. Thanks for the help.

Comment: [Can't reproduce when simply scraping the site](http://hastebin.com/godeyeyeva). When commenting out the file handling, I get exactly the same results. I don't think the problem is in this function.